# Little Database Performance Puzzle

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design

I am not really experienced with databases but I have a little problem. I am trying to create a database that stores the courses being taken by students and lecturers so I created three tables. In the lecturer and student tables, the field courses represent a comma separated list of the courses taken by either the lecturer or the student.

*Something like this:*

> Lecturer - Courses - "1,2"
>
> Student - Courses - "1,2,3"
>
> Courses - 1 - "Bio"

The problem however is that when I want to show a list of student based on their courses, I have to search all the students and the courses and search again to check whether the csv list has the specified course (which seems a bit redundant). Is there another way I can achieve this goal, say by relating/referencing the indexes or something? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create two new tables:

```
student_courses(int student_id, int course_id)
lecturer_courses(int lecturer_id, int course_id)
```

You can now create individual rows for each course a student is taking and each course a lecturer is teaching, assuming that you want to track delivery of a course separate from taking the course.  You can then write queries against those tables using course id when you want to do course related analysis.

Answer (score 4):

> the field courses represent a comma separated list of the courses taken by either the lecturer or the student

A field that contains a `csv list` is breaking [First Normal Form (1NF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and has all sorts of problems, including performance. Breaking out this field into a separate Junction Table `{StudentID, CourseID}` is what you should do.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing a text like "1,2,3", store several rows:

- 1 row for every student in a table named "students"
- 1 row for every course in a table named "courses"

Then create another table named "student_in_course" which has 1 row for every combination.

Then do the same for "lecturer_in_course".